# SSH Remote Code Execution Script over Jumphost (Nested Quotes)

Tags: bash, awk, ssh, quotes, remote-execution

Consider the following infrastructure:
`ServerA ---> ServerB ---> ServerC`

I want to get large files from `ServerC` (thus filtering them first) and save them on `ServerA` by running a script on `ServerA`.

The following command successfully retrieves all filenames matching my pattern and saves it in variable `$myfiles`:

```
myfiles=$(ssh root@$serverB -C $"\
          ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no root@$serverC -C $'\
          (find . -name "mypattern" | sort)' </dev/null")
```

Instead of just transmitting the data I have to filter them first with the following command:

```
grep mypattern $myfile | awk -F '[| =]+' '{print $1 "/" $2 "/" $3, $4}' OFS=';'
```

Now, here I am running into nested quoting issues because awk splits the command with its single quotes:

```
while read myfile
do
   output=$( ssh root@$serverB -C $"\
             ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no root@$serverC -C $'\
             (grep mypattern $myfile | awk -F '[| =]+' '{print $1 "/" $2 "/" $3, $4}' OFS=';')'\
             </dev/null")
   # do something with $output
done <<< "$myfiles"
```

Is there any way to get it run in this nested way?

**Note:** The ssh jumphost flag should not work as ServerC can only be accessed using the ssh command with StrictHostKeyChecking flag on ServerB.

Exchanging the quotes from single to double leads to a similar issue. I have also tried preparing the command as string, function and in a separate file without success.

Comment: Is `grep mypattern $myfile` supposed to be `grep mypattern $file`, i.e. using your loop variable `file` instead of the unset variable `myfile`?

Comment: `grep foo file | awk '{bar}'` = `awk '/foo/{bar}' file` by the way. You never need grep when you're using awk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I would do, using shell *here-doc*:

```
while read file; do
   output=$(
       ssh root@$serverB <<-EOF1
             ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no root@$serverC <<-EOF2
             grep mypattern $myfile | awk -F '[| =]+' '{print \\\$1 "/" \\\$2 "/" \\\$3, \\\$4}' OFS=';'
             EOF2
        EOF1
   )
   # do something with $output
done <<< "$myfiles"
```

In the left part of *here-doc*, you have to use tabs, not spaces.

Comment: This way the arguments inside the print statement get removed:

`awk: cmd. line:1: {print  "/"  "/" , }`
`awk: cmd. line:1:                  ^ syntax error`

Comment: Try doubling the escapes, e.g. `print \\$1`, since you have 2 layers of ssh parsing it.

Comment: @EdMorton With double escapes `print \\$1` gets evaluated by the arguments the scripts uses instead of selecting the column: `awk: cmd. line:1: {print \-c "/" \script_argument1 "/" \-i, \script_argument2, \ \}`

Comment: @xard then try triple. Usually when a variable is being expanded before you want it to you can solve the problem by throwing escapes at it.

Comment: @xard: have you tried triple backslashes?

Comment: @EdMorton Triple backslashes did the trick, thanks!